# PowerShell Get-ItemProperty returns wrong binary value

Tags: powershell

I have a weird issue. I'm trying to get a binary value from the registry and import that value to another computer.

I'm using

```
$key = "HKCU:\Software\TestKey\001"
(Get-ItemProperty -Path $key)."myValue"
```

Returns:
68 0 101 0 102 0 97 0 117 0 108 0 116 0 0 0

but the value in registry is: 
44 00 65 00 66 00 61 00 75 00 6C 00 74 00 00 00

I've tried almost everything. [System.BitConverter]::ToString() 
returns the correct value. But when I try to add that back to registry as a binary value, I get an error that it's not in the correct format.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong and give me example how to export then import a binary value using Powershell?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're getting the correct value; your return is expressed in decimal, whereas the value in the registry is expressed in hex. How are you trying to "add it back" to the registry?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Jeff. I am exporting value to a text and on the other computer getting the content then  adding it as "new-itemproperty -path $path -value $content -propertytype binary -force"

Comment: Why not just use regedit to export the key and then just apply the resulting .reg file to the other computer(s)?

Comment: I thought about that but there are lots of keys that I don't need. I only need one value.

Comment: Edit out the data that you don't need.

Comment: that would be my last option. I just wanted to see if there is an easier way.

Comment: http://www.peetersonline.nl/2009/01/from-hex-to-dec-and-back/  --- some handy functions to convert between hexidecimal <> decimal <> octal, might assist here

Comment: I had already try that. But when I try to add it to the registry I get an error "Cannot convert value 6c to type system.byte. Input string was not in a correct format

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from native command prompt.

`reg export /?`